# ASP.Net Membership Your Thoughts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am building a project using ASP.Net 4 and MVC3 using C#.
The ASP.Net Membership Provider is integrated well into the framework.
Role check and some identity information but I have an issue.
It's limited flexibility.
Should I build a new user management system from the ground up and lose the convenient short codes within controllers ect....?
Are there any alternative?

Worry about hashing passwords, caching stuff, session management just gives me a headache when I think about building something from scratch.

Comment: Define "Limited Flexibility." What do you intend to do that the default Membership Provider won't allow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlMembershipProvider vs a custom solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445260/sqlmembershipprovider-vs-a-custom-solutions). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862222 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973820

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the ASP Membership mainly for logging-in (only).  Then I use database-specific tables for highly-customized user-features that ASP Membership doesn't easily accomodate (or at all).  If any custom-feature "can" be (easily) accomodated by the ASP Membership Db...then I use it...but mostly, I put custom user-specific functionality in the target database (in-question).

Also...

Because the ASP Membership functionality can manage many databases at the same time, I run a separate ASP Membership database instance (apart) from those it manages.  Doings so has proven clean & friendly for me.

Comment: This is exactly what we do. Just outsource the password to the sqlmembership db, and track your users separately in the application db. We even use our own custom RoleProvider. +1 for keeping membership db separate from application db. It can be more expensive, but worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be a lot of advantage in writing your own membership system 'from the ground up'.

You'd be better implementing a custom Membership Provider and Role Provider - meaning that you can easily use the [Authorize] attribute, and other built in membership roles stuff, and then add any extra stuff you need into your custom providers.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) to see what is involved in a MembershipProvider and RoleProvider - just derive from the abstract MembershipProvider and RoleProvider and provide your own implementations